# Prove that $\frac{n^2}{2} - 3n = \Theta(n^2)$

Tags: asymptotics

The question is,

> Prove that $\frac{n^2}{2} - 3n = \Theta(n^2)$.

I understand that to do this I must determine positive constants $c_1$, $c_2$, and $n_0$ such that
$$c_1n^2 \leq \frac{n^2}{2} - 3n  \leq c_2n^2$$

I simplified by dividing by $n^2$ which left

$$c_1 \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n} \leq c_2$$

The book I am following along with says "We can make the right-hand inequality hold for any value of $n \geq 1$ by choosing any constant $c_2 \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Likewise, we can make the left-hand inequality hold for any value of $n \geq 7$ by choosing any constant $c_1 \leq \frac{1}{14}$."

I understand that there are other choices for the constants but I'm not sure of a method for determining them. What general procedure should I use for determining these other than guess and check?

Comment: For polynomials, determining an upper constant can be done by ignoring all negative terms and increasing the order of all positive terms to match the highest ordered term.  For example $10n^5-2n^4-3n^3+n^2+5n \leq 10n^5+n^2+5n\leq 10n^5+n^5+5n^5\leq 16n^5$.  Finding lower bounds takes a bit more effort to explain but a similar approach can sometimes work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did so far was good. Then, to determine an exact choice for the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, you should think carefully about the expression, in this case
$$
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n}.
$$
As $n$ gets larger, what does this sequence do? Well, it gets closer and closer to $\frac12$. And it only increases; it gets closer to $\frac12$ from below.

That means we can pick the upper bound $c_2 = \frac12$. And since it increases, we can pick the lower bound $c_1$ to be the $n$th term for some suitably large $n$. In the book, they picked $n = 7$ to get $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{7} = \frac{1}{14}$ as the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your task doesn't really require you to specify the constants. One approach for the solution would be to state that the sequence
$$ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n} $$
converges to the constant $ \frac{1}{2} $. This means that for any $ \varepsilon > 0 $ there exists $ N(\varepsilon)$ such that $ \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n} < \frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon $ for $n > N(\varepsilon) $, which gives you the two constans for all sufficiently large $ n $ (i.e. larger than $ N(\varepsilon) $)

Answer (score 0):

**Lets find first constant:**
$$\begin{array}{l}\left| {\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n} \right| \le {c_1}.{n^2} \to if\;\;n \ge 6\;\;then\;\;\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \ge 0\\So,\;we\;can\;say\;\;\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \le {c_1}.{n^2}\;\;;\;\;n \ge 6\;\;instead\;of\;\left| {\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n} \right| \le {c_1}.{n^2}\\Let\;\;{c_1} = \frac{1}{2} \to \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \le \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} \to  - 3n \le 0 \to n \ge 0\;\;Obvious\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaadaabda
% qaamaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikda
% aaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gaaiaawEa7caGLiWoacqGHKjYOcaWGJb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaaiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaa
% ikdaaaGccqGHsgIRcaWGPbGaamOzaiaaysW7caaMe8UaamOBaiabgw
% MiZkaaiAdacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadshacaWGObGaamyzaiaad6gacaaM
% e8UaaGjbVpaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaai
% aaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIWaaabaGaam4u
% aiaad+gacaGGSaGaaGjbVlaadEhacaWGLbGaaGjbVlaadogacaWGHb
% GaamOBaiaaysW7caWGZbGaamyyaiaadMhacaaMe8UaaGjbVpaalaaa
% baGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0
% IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHKjYOcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGa
% aiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccaaMe8UaaGjbVlaacU
% dacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaad6gacqGHLjYScaaI2aGaaGjbVlaaysW7caWG
% PbGaamOBaiaadohacaWG0bGaamyzaiaadggacaWGKbGaaGjbVlaad+
% gacaWGMbGaaGzaVlaaysW7daabdaqaamaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaa
% leqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gaai
% aawEa7caGLiWoacqGHKjYOcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGa
% aiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaacaWGmbGaamyzai
% aadshacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaGccqGH
% 9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaaaaiabgkziUoaalaaabaGaam
% OBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4m
% aiaad6gacqGHKjYOdaWcaaqaaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaa
% aakeaacaaIYaaaaiabgkziUkabgkHiTiaaiodacaWGUbGaeyizImQa
% aGimaiabgkziUkaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIWaGaaGjbVlaaysW7caWGpb
% GaamOyaiaadAhacaWGPbGaam4BaiaadwhacaWGZbaaaaa!D2D5!
$$
According to the initial assumption:
$$n \ge 6 \to {n_0} = 6,\;\;{c_1} = 0.5 \to \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \le \frac{1}{2}{n^2}\;for\;any\;n \ge 6\;\;(A)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOBaiabgw
% MiZkaaiAdacqGHsgIRcaWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyyp
% a0JaaGOnaiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaa
% qabaGccqGH9aqpcaaIWaGaaiOlaiaaiwdacqGHsgIRdaWcaaqaaiaa
% d6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaacaaIYaaaaiabgkHiTiaaio
% dacaWGUbGaeyizIm6aaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaacaWGUbWa
% aWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaaGjbVlaadAgacaWGVbGaamOCaiaays
% W7caWGHbGaamOBaiaadMhacaaMe8UaamOBaiabgwMiZkaaiAdacaaM
% e8UaaGjbVlaacIcacaWGbbGaaiykaaaa!672A!
$$
**Lets find second constant:**
$$\begin{array}{l}\left| {\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n} \right| \ge {c_2}.{n^2} \to if\;\;n \ge 6\;\;then\;\;\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \ge 0\\So,\;we\;can\;say\;\;\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \ge {c_2}.{n^2}\;\;;\;\;n \ge 6\;\;instead\;of\;\left| {\frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n} \right| \ge {c_2}.{n^2}\\ \to (\frac{1}{2} - {c_2})\,{n^2} - 3n \ge 0 \to n \times ((\frac{1}{2} - {c_2})\;n - 3) \ge 0 \to \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{n \le 0\;\; \times \quad \quad \quad }\\{Or}\\{n \ge 3/(0.5 - {c_2})}\end{array}} \right.\\ \to n \ge \frac{3}{{0.5 - {c_2}}}\;\;(B)\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaadaabda
% qaamaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikda
% aaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gaaiaawEa7caGLiWoacqGHLjYScaWGJb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaaiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaa
% ikdaaaGccqGHsgIRcaWGPbGaamOzaiaaysW7caaMe8UaamOBaiabgw
% MiZkaaiAdacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadshacaWGObGaamyzaiaad6gacaaM
% e8UaaGjbVpaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaai
% aaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIWaaabaGaam4u
% aiaad+gacaGGSaGaaGjbVlaadEhacaWGLbGaaGjbVlaadogacaWGHb
% GaamOBaiaaysW7caWGZbGaamyyaiaadMhacaaMe8UaaGjbVpaalaaa
% baGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0
% IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHLjYScaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGa
% aiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccaaMe8UaaGjbVlaacU
% dacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaad6gacqGHLjYScaaI2aGaaGjbVlaaysW7caWG
% PbGaamOBaiaadohacaWG0bGaamyzaiaadggacaWGKbGaaGjbVlaad+
% gacaWGMbGaaGzaVlaaysW7daabdaqaamaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaa
% leqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gaai
% aawEa7caGLiWoacqGHLjYScaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGa
% aiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaacqGHsgIRcaGGOa
% WaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaacqGHsislcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqa
% aiaaikdaaeqaaOGaaiykaiaaykW7caWGUbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYa
% aaaOGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIWaGaeyOKH4QaamOB
% aiabgEna0kaacIcacaGGOaWaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaacq
% GHsislcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaaiykaiaaysW7caWG
% UbGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaacMcacqGHLjYScaaIWaGaeyOKH46aaiqaae
% aafaqabeWabaaabaGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaaicdacaaMe8UaaGjbVlab
% gEna0kaaywW7caaMf8UaaGzbVdqaaiaad+eacaWGYbaabaGaamOBai
% abgwMiZkaaiodacaGGVaGaaiikaiaaicdacaGGUaGaaGynaiabgkHi
% TiaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaGccaGGPaaaaaGaay5Eaaaaba
% GaeyOKH4QaamOBaiabgwMiZoaalaaabaGaaG4maaqaaiaaicdacaGG
% UaGaaGynaiabgkHiTiaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaaaaOGaaG
% jbVlaaysW7caGGOaGaamOqaiaacMcaaaaa!F62C!
$$
According to the initial assumption:
$$\begin{array}{l}n \ge 6 \to \frac{3}{{0.5 - {c_2}}} \ge 6 \to \frac{1}{{0.5 - {c_2}}} \ge 2 \to 0 < 0.5 - {c_2} \le 0.5 \to  - 0.5 <  - {c_2} \le 0 \to {c_2} < 0.5\\Let\;\;{c_2} = \frac{1}{3}\;\;optionally \to Considering\;(B),\;we\;can\;say\;\;n \ge \frac{3}{{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}}} \to n \ge 18\\n \ge 18 \to {n_0} = 18,\;\;{c_2} = \frac{1}{3} \to \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \ge \frac{1}{3}{n^2}\;for\;any\;n \ge 18\;\;(C)\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGUb
% GaeyyzImRaaGOnaiabgkziUoaalaaabaGaaG4maaqaaiaaicdacaGG
% UaGaaGynaiabgkHiTiaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaaaaOGaey
% yzImRaaGOnaiabgkziUoaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaicdacaGGUaGa
% aGynaiabgkHiTiaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaaaaOGaeyyzIm
% RaaGOmaiabgkziUkaaicdacqGH8aapcaaIWaGaaiOlaiaaiwdacqGH
% sislcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaeyizImQaaGimaiaac6
% cacaaI1aGaeyOKH4QaeyOeI0IaaGimaiaac6cacaaI1aGaeyipaWJa
% eyOeI0Iaam4yamaaBaaaleaacaaIYaaabeaakiabgsMiJkaaicdacq
% GHsgIRcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaeyipaWJaaGimaiaa
% c6cacaaI1aaabaGaamitaiaadwgacaWG0bGaaGjbVlaaysW7caWGJb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGa
% aG4maaaacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaad+gacaWGWbGaamiDaiaadMgacaWGVb
% GaamOBaiaadggacaWGSbGaamiBaiaadMhacqGHsgIRcaWGdbGaam4B
% aiaad6gacaWGZbGaamyAaiaadsgacaWGLbGaamOCaiaadMgacaWGUb
% Gaam4zaiaaysW7caGGOaGaamOqaiaacMcacaGGSaGaaGjbVlaadEha
% caWGLbGaaGjbVlaadogacaWGHbGaamOBaiaaysW7caWGZbGaamyyai
% aadMhacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaad6gacqGHLjYSdaWcaaqaaiaaiodaaeaa
% daWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaaaaiabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaaGymaa
% qaaiaaiodaaaaaaiabgkziUkaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIXaGaaGioaaqa
% aiaad6gacqGHLjYScaaIXaGaaGioaiabgkziUkaad6gadaWgaaWcba
% GaaGimaaqabaGccqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaaGioaiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjb
% VlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaGccqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaig
% daaeaacaaIZaaaaiabgkziUoaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGa
% aGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHLjYSda
% WcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIZaaaaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikda
% aaGccaaMe8UaamOzaiaad+gacaWGYbGaaGjbVlaadggacaWGUbGaam
% yEaiaaysW7caWGUbGaeyyzImRaaGymaiaaiIdacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaa
% cIcacaWGdbGaaiykaaaaaa!E390!
$$
**Finally:**
$$\begin{array}{l}(A),\;(C) \to \frac{1}{3}{n^2} \le \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \le \frac{1}{2}{n^2}\;\;for\;any\;n \ge 18\\ \to if\;\;{c_1} = \frac{1}{2},\;\;{c_2} = \frac{1}{3}\;\;and\;{n_0} = 18\;\;then\;we\;can\;say:\\\exists {c_1},\;{c_2},\;{n_0},\;\;\forall n \ge {n_0} \to {c_2}.{n^2} \le \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \le {c_1}.{n^2} \to \frac{{{n^2}}}{2} - 3n \in \theta \;({n^2})\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaGGOa
% GaamyqaiaacMcacaGGSaGaaGjbVlaacIcacaWGdbGaaiykaiabgkzi
% UoaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaiodaaaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaG
% OmaaaakiabgsMiJoaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaa
% aOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGHKjYOdaWcaaqaai
% aaigdaaeaacaaIYaaaaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccaaM
% e8UaaGjbVlaadAgacaWGVbGaamOCaiaaysW7caWGHbGaamOBaiaadM
% hacaaMe8UaamOBaiabgwMiZkaaigdacaaI4aaabaGaeyOKH4QaamyA
% aiaadAgacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaGccq
% GH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaaaaiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjb
% VlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaGccqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaig
% daaeaacaaIZaaaaiaaysW7caaMe8Uaamyyaiaad6gacaWGKbGaaGjb
% Vlaad6gadaWgaaWcbaGaaGimaaqabaGccqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaaGioai
% aaysW7caaMe8UaamiDaiaadIgacaWGLbGaamOBaiaaysW7caWG3bGa
% amyzaiaaysW7caWGJbGaamyyaiaad6gacaaMe8Uaam4Caiaadggaca
% WG5bGaaiOoaaqaaiabgoGiKiaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaGc
% caGGSaGaaGjbVlaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaGccaGGSaGaaG
% jbVlaad6gadaWgaaWcbaGaaGimaaqabaGccaGGSaGaaGjbVlaaysW7
% cqGHaiIicaWGUbGaeyyzImRaamOBamaaBaaaleaacaaIWaaabeaaki
% abgkziUkaadogadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaGccaGGUaGaamOBamaa
% CaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgsMiJoaalaaabaGaamOBamaaCaaale
% qabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaaikdaaaGaeyOeI0IaaG4maiaad6gacqGH
% KjYOcaWGJbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaaiOlaiaad6gadaahaa
% WcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHsgIRdaWcaaqaaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqa
% aiaaikdaaaaakeaacaaIYaaaaiabgkHiTiaaiodacaWGUbGaeyicI4
% SaeqiUdeNaaGjbVlaacIcacaWGUbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGa
% aiykaaaaaa!C7F2!
$$